# Django on Nginx subdirectory redirects to root

Tags: django, nginx

I have Django 2.2 and am trying to serve it to http://myserver.com/application using Nginx proxy pass.

If I try and go to myserver.com/application/admin I get redirect to myserver.com/admin immediately.

Is this a setting I should be specifying in Nginx or in Django to avoid this? Django is running in gunicorn, see Nginx.conf:

```
location /static {
        alias /home/simernes/workspace/django_server/env/static;
    }

location /application {
        proxy_pass                http://localhost:8000/;
        proxy_redirect            off;
        proxy_set_header          Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header          X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-Proto  http;
        proxy_buffer_size         128k;
        proxy_buffers             8 128k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    }
```

Finally, this is what my urls.py looks like in a project folder "backend":

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url, include

FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME="/application"
STATIC_ROOT="/home/simernes/workspace/django_server/env/static/"
app_name='backend'
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('api.urls', namespace='api')),
]
```

Furthermore, when I go to the root of myserver.com/application I get an error of 404 not found and:

```
Using the URLconf defined in backend.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    ^ auth$ [name='auth']

The current path, /, didn't match any of these.
```

Which is not what I expected, as I am configuring to show the urls available in my api app (see urls.py below), but it's not my main concern with this question so I'm just including it for broader context.

I have another app folder called api with urls also, which is the one being included in backend:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework.authtoken import views as drf_views

app_name="api"
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'auth$', drf_views.obtain_auth_token, name='auth'),
]
```

Thanks in advance for any responses, they will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also override `LOGIN_URL`, `STATIC_URL`, `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` and any other settings that require a path

Comment: So in my case, what should they be?